# How to create a gmail-api access scope for social emails only

Tags: gmail-api

## gmail-api

Here is the use case:

I am a client to Gmail API. I want to create an access token which scope is similar to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly". But, instead of Gmail giving me access to all the emails, I would like to have access to the social emails ONLY.

Speculation for social emails scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.social.readonly

Note:
Social emails have a **CATEGORY_SOCIAL** label.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This feature currently doesn't exist, but I would recommend viewing [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760255) feature request which is very similar to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoping access at the label level is not possible. The scopes listed in the [**Choose Auth Scopes**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) section are the only ones available. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly` is the one you have to go with.

Comment: Hi Tholle, I would not like to have access to ALL my users' e-mails. For example, my idea is that users allow an application to access their emails under the social category only. Unfortunately, gmail.readonly scope is to broad for my purpose.

Comment: Scoping access at the label level is simply not possible. Tholle's answer is correct.